# My script is ticking up at random intervals and only works on one person

Tags: lua, roblox

im trying to make a game that shows you how long you have survived and ive made a lobby and im trying to make a script that starts ticking up by 1 when you touch the teleporter that gets you out of the lobby. it works but it only gives it to one person and randomly ticks up. how do i fix it?

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
     leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
     money = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    money.Name = "TimeSurvived"
end)
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local part = script.Parent
    if hit then
        while true do
            money.Value = money.Value +1
            wait(1)
        end
    end
end)
```

i tried to make a part that teleports you and starts ticking up the laederstat by one but it ticks up at random intervals and only works for one person

Comment: `money` appears to be global, thus you overwrite it each time someone joins.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues.

1. Using global variables to access player's money:

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
```

The event `PlayerAdded` is invoked every time a player joins the game, and since `leaderstats` is stored as a global variable (one variable accessible anywhere from your script), every time a player joins the value of this variable is overwritten with the new player's `leaderstats`, making it so when you try to access it again later, you actually just access the `leaderstats` of latest player to join the game.
You should simply use a local variable instead, because you shouldn't be accessing the player's data like this anyways.

```lua
local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
```

This also applies to `money`.

2. Not properly checking which part is touching.

The `Touched` event of the part you have here (`script.Parent`) passes a `hit` parameter which indicates what part touched your part, and this works with any part.
So if your game spawns some raining tacos and one of them touches your part, that event will be invoked.

To fix this, you have to filter out non-character parts. Since a character's parts are grouped together in a model that contains a `Humanoid`, you can check if `hit.Parent` has a `Humanoid` in it like this:

```lua
if hit:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid") then
```

Now, you want to find the **PLAYER** that controls this character, because NPC/enemy/etc characters also have `Humanoid`s in them. For this you want to use `game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)`, where `character` is the parent of the hit part, like this:

```lua
-- Make sure that 'hit.Parent' is a character first!!
local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
if plr then
    plr.leaderstats.TimeSurvived.Value += 1
end
```

Note: `value += 1` is the same as `value = value + 1` but shorter ;)

3. Creating a new loop whenever the part is touched. Every time a character (any part in your code) touches the part here, a new loop is created to increment the money, which means more money gets added every second, to fix this just remove the loop or keep a track of players who have already touched the part in a table, and only create a new loop if they have no record of touching the part already.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Global variable causing a shared timer amongst players.**
2. **Missing player-specific data in leaderstats.**
3. **No check for touching player, leading to potential errors.**

The corrected code for #3 is below this

```lua
     script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
                local part = script.Parent
                local character = hit.Parent
                local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character) -- this checks if (hit) is actually a players model
                
                if player then -- if the hit is a player then it runs code 
                    while true do --inf loop
                        local leaderstats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") --finds the parent players leaderstats folder
                        if leaderstats then -- if leaderstats exists then it runs the code below
                            local money = leaderstats:FindFirstChild("TimeSurvived") -- finds if "TimedSurvived"'s IntValue in the leaderstats folder if not then it will not run
                            if money then
                                money.Value = money.Value + 1
                            end
                        end
                        wait(1)
                    end
                end
            end)
```